# how to find the same value in a javascript map

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have one javascript map, in the map the values have the same value, i want to create new map for each map value to store all the same values key pair. I mean based on the map values to create new map, each value create one new map in the new map the key still the key and the value still the same.

```
//map is dynamics created base on data from api call
const mainMap = new map();
//Fill map with data
//In the map it has been filled from api
//The data is dyanmic below is just sample 
mainMap.set(1,a);
mainMap.set(2,b);
mainMap.set(3,c);
mainMap.set(4,a);
mainMap.set(5,c);
mainMap.set(6,b);
mainMap.set(7,c);
mainMap.set(8,a);
mainMap.set(9,c);
mainMap.set(10,c);
mainMap.set(11,a);
mainMap.set(12,c);
mainMap.set(13,a);
mainMap.set(14,c);
mainMap.set(15,c);
mainMap.set(16,e);
mainMap.set(17,f);
......

//find out the same values key and create new map, basically each value will create one new map
const newMap1 = new map();
newMap1.set(1,a)
newMap1.set(4,a);
newMap1.set(8,a);
newMap1.set(11,a);
newMap1.set(13,a);

const newMap2 = new map();
newMap2.set(2,b);
newMap2.set(6,b);

const newMap3 = new map();
newMap3.set(3,c);
newMap3.set(5,c);
newMap3.set(7,c);
newMap3.set(9,c);
newMap3.set(10,c);
newMap3.set(12,c);
newMap3.set(14,c);
newMap3.set(15,c);

const newMap4 = new map();
newMap4.set(16,e);

const newMap5 = new map();
newMap5.set(17,f);


......
```

Thank you guys in advance

I tried to divide the main map into small sub maps by finding the same value but not able to do it.

Comment: please add some examples what you have and what you like to get.

Comment: `new map()` should be `new Map()`. JS is case-sensitive.

Comment: Don't use multiple maps for the result. Use a map that maps the value to an array of keys. You can do this by looping over the entries in the original map, updating the result map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a way of creating an object `res` containing the maps a, b, c, e, and f. In the console output below I use a quick "map to object" conversion in order to list each map's content as if it were an object:

```
Object.fromEntries(map.entries())
```

```js
const mainMap = new Map();
//Fill map with data
//In the map it has been filled from api
//The data is dynamic below is just sample 
mainMap.set(1,'a');
mainMap.set(2,'b');
mainMap.set(3,'c');
mainMap.set(4,'a');
mainMap.set(5,'c');
mainMap.set(6,'b');
mainMap.set(7,'c');
mainMap.set(8,'a');
mainMap.set(9,'c');
mainMap.set(10,'c');
mainMap.set(11,'a');
mainMap.set(12,'c');
mainMap.set(13,'a');
mainMap.set(14,'c');
mainMap.set(15,'c');
mainMap.set(16,'e');
mainMap.set(17,'f');

const res={};
mainMap.forEach((v,k)=>(res[v]??=[]).push([k,v]));
Object.entries(res).forEach(([k,arr])=>
  res[k]=new Map(arr))
 
// Show the results 
Object.entries(res).forEach(([k,map])=>{
 console.log(k);
 console.log(Object.fromEntries(map.entries()));
});
```

Comment: Thank you so mcuh @Carsten Massmann.  That's what i want, in my app i will proceed those data.